# PySpark - Connecting to HBASE using PySpark - Package import failing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I am facing an issue when connecting to HBASE using PySpark as it fails with an error as:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.load.
>   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

- HDP Version : 2.6.4.0-91
- Spark Ver:  2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
- Python: 2.7.5
- Jar used: /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/shc/shc-core-1.1.0.2.6.4.0-91.jar

I tried jar import using `pyspark --jars /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/shc/shc-core-1.1.0.2.6.4.0-91.jar`

It takes to PySpark's shell with the prompt, but when I try to connect to HBASE, it fails with the error mentioned above.

Sample Code Executed:

```
Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, May 31 2018 09:41:32)

SparkSession available as 'spark'.

>>> catalog = ''.join("""{'table': {'namespace': 'default','name': 'books'},'rowkey': 'key','columns': {'title': {'cf': 'rowkey', 'col': 'key', 'type': 'string'},'author': {'cf': 'info', 'col': 'author', 'type': 'string'}}}""".split())
>>> 
>>> df = sqlContext.read.options(catalog=catalog).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').load()
```

> Failing with error given below:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase

Answer (score 0):

Try with using **`--packages`** and **`--repositories`** arguments as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc).

```
bash$ export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2

bash$ pyspark --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *

>>> spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate() 

>>> catalog = ''.join("""{'table': {'namespace': 'default','name': 'books'},'rowkey': 'key','columns': {'title': {'cf': 'rowkey', 'col': 'key', 'type': 'string'},'author': {'cf': 'info', 'col': 'author', 'type': 'string'}}}""".split())

>>> df=spark.read.options(catalog=catalog,newtable=5).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").load()
```